# What are these black edges appearing on my object? Would really appreciate help!

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image: Bolt showing black edges]

I've got this issue which appears when I've created this bolt. What's worse is that they appear even when I render the object - it looks like there's black paint on the metal model. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: It could be several things, but it looks like our bolt is reflecting something dar from the environment.  Please add your blend file so we can better help you. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: If you've shaded smooth your object, you need to enable the Auto Smooth option and play with the value. If it's not the problem here, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thank you- switching the Auto Smooth option worked. I selected the bolt, went on object properties (green triangle) > Normals > tick-boxed 'Auto Smooth' . Super helpful, thank you :)